# Whats so special with ThreadAbortException?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0

As we know  , [Server.Transfer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z9e2zxx%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) throws *ThreadAbortException* when executed.

Also , ThreadAbortException inherits Exception  :

[image]

So why the exception wont enter the catch block in  :

```
  try
   {
         Server.Transfer("NoPremissionSell.aspx");
   }

  catch (Exception  e)
   { }
```

while it will in :

```
  try
   {
         Server.Transfer("NoPremissionSell.aspx");
   }

  catch (ThreadAbortException e)
   { }
```

## edit   ,

This is working  in both 2 scenarios. I don't know why it didnt work before.
please ignore.

sorry for misleading.

Comment: `Excception` shoudl be `Exception`

Comment: Both catch the exception fine when I try it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A number of exception types are treated differently by the .NET runtime (the Command Language Infrastructure, CLI, that underlies the execution of assemblies).

Eg. [`StackOverflowException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stackoverflowexception.aspx) cannot be caught *at all* by .NET code.

The reason for this depends on the exception. In the case of `StackOverflowException` because the CLI cannot guarantee the correctness of the state of the process.

In the case of a [`ThreadAbortException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadabortexception.aspx) the special treatment is because while it can be caught it must be re-thrown (automatically) so the thread will end.

Answer (score 2):

ThreadAbortException is special in that, even if it is caught, it will automatically be rethrown. The thread has been aborted. The code can clean up but not stop the abort unless [Thread.ResetAbort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.resetabort.aspx) is called. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadabortexception.aspx for more information.

Comment: You say "not stop the abort", but the very page you link to says in the remarks "... or call `Thread.ResetAbort` to cancel the abort, there is no guarantee that the thread will ever end"

Answer (score 2):

It is not true that you cannot catch ThreadAbortException via catch (Exception).

The following code prints "Handled Exception: Thread was being aborted.", proving that the exception was indeed caught:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                test();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Handled Exception: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        static void test()
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.Abort();
        }
    }
}
```

How were you testing whether the exception was caught?